# IE background image not showing

Tags: html, css, background

Having a small problem where the background image is not showing in any of the IE versions (except IE 9 I believe), not sure what is going wrong, any helps/thoughts/things I could try out?

Kind regards

http://www.trucknetuk.com/phpBB/viewforum.php?f=46  It is the Michelin banner(not the small sponsor) just above the new topic button

background: url("./styles/Owner_Fleet_Operator_MS/theme/images/michelinback.gif") repeat-x scroll center 0 transparent;

Comment: show some of your code to expect answer...

Comment: I thought it was better to see the link with firebug..

Comment: no one will put an effort without any clue or code and everyone is not using firebug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
background: url('./styles/Owner_Fleet_Operator_MS/theme/images/michelinback.gif')repeat-x scroll center 0 transparent;
```

To this:

```
background: url('./styles/Owner_Fleet_Operator_MS/theme/images/michelinback.gif') repeat-x scroll center 0 transparent;
```

The difference is a space after the closing bracket and before the "repeat-x". IE is much pickier than other browsers regarding syntax.

Comment: Awesome, that did the job, actually in firebug it said it had a space, but then I checked in the style and it did not. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your background shorthand is wrong, `transparent` needs to come first

```
#page-body {
    background: transparent url("./styles/Owner_Fleet_Operator_MS/theme/images/michelinback.gif") repeat-x center 0;
    clear: both;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}
```

proper shorthand is : `body {background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;}`

Not sure what you are trying to do with the `scroll` declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
.button{
      background: transparent url('../images/backrgound.jpg') no-repeat top center;
}
```

**CSS Standard**

background : *color URL repeat-section and position*

**JPEG Images**

Check whether images are of JPEG2000, if yes, then open any image editor and save it again with proper jpeg extension